# What is the effective area of VLASS?

Tags: radio-astronomy

I need to calculate NRAO VLA Sky Surveys effective area that's been held in 1998. (The observation of 1.4GHz NRAO VLA Sky Survey (NVSS) (Condon+ 1998)). I couldn't find the exact values, tried many times. But I cannot find a decent source to confirm the area of each antennas' surface. So, basically i know that $$\pi*r^2*n_{antenna}$$ will be the effective area of VLASS. Where $$n_{antenna}$$ is 27. So i just need the $$r$$ of them but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in the question would provide the physical aperture, but the value of interest is the effective aperture which accounts for non-uniform [illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_antenna#Feed_pattern) of the dish reflectors by the feed.

$$A_e = n \eta \pi r^2$$

Where $A_e$ is the effective aperture, $n$ is the number of antennas, $\eta$ is the [aperture efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_(antenna)#Aperture_efficiency), and $r$ is the dish diameter.

Each of the 27 [Very Large Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Array) (VLA) antennas has a diameter of 25 meters, so $r = 12.5m$.  According to [Efficiency at L-band on the Expanded Very Large Array Synthesis Telescope](https://www.ursi.org/proceedings/procGA05/pdf/J01-P.10(0734).pdf) the aperture efficiency at 1425 MHz (1.425 GHz) is 0.43.

Combining all of these:

$$A_e = 27 \cdot 0.43 \cdot \pi \cdot (12.5m)^2 = 6.20\times10^3 m^2$$

Comment: Okay that looks so right. However, also I cannot catch where i used to this A_e thing to calculate Flux from Jansky, then Luminosity by that Flux. I know this A_e is having a huge part and effect on Flux. But I'm not a radio astronomer so my knowledge is the limiting thing.

Comment: Is it just L = S * 4π * D^2 * ν, where S is the flux in Janskies. Or L = Jansky * A_e * 4π * D^2 * ν is it what should be? But units cannot match.